# Can someone explain to me how this code works in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
mounted(){

this.$root.$on('dataLoaded', (magazineData) => {
    this.LoadData(magazineData);
});

}
```

From what I've understand it calls when dataLoaded is changed on the parent element and the magazineData is a variable inside the parent is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magazineData  is a parameter emitted when @dataLoaded. It depends of what kind of page you're loading.